# Logstash-input-mongodb conf file

Tags: mongodb, plugins, input, logstash

This is considered to be the Conf file for MongoDB input plugin.

What does the Path

> path => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/logstash_sqlite.db'   refers to.
>   where to find that logstash_sqlite.db or what file does it point to.

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://10.0.0.30/my-logs?ssl=true'
    path => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'events_'
    unpack_mongo_id => true
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide permissions for the logstash on the /opt/logstash-mongodb so it will be able to create the database:

```
sudo chown -R logstash:logstash /opt/logstash-mongodb
```